# TimeZone information in .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, mono, timezone

Could anybody suggest a third party library in .net which could provide Time Zone information and meet these requirements

1. Which supports .NET 2.0 not .net 3.5
   ***Note: (.NET 3.5 has a class called TimeZoneInfo).***
2. Mono compatible

Ta,
Rajeesh

Answer (score 2):

http://www.codeplex.com/publicdomain

Uses the Olsen TimeZone Database. Hence think it also works historically, have found in the past that the TimeZoneInfo class does not work when the rules have changed.

Think it is Mono compatible.

Comment: I think it is not mono compatible, when I analyzed that dll with [MoMa](www.mono-project.com/MoMA), it is showing some errors(line Use of P/Invoke methods)

Comment: The parts to do with the TimeZone stuff do not use the PInvoke code, I believe this is isolated to the Win32.cs files, which you can remove from the project and then compile.  
I ran MoMaA on the resulting assembly and it said 'No P/Invokes are called' after this. It did say that there are 9 MonoTodo but I do not think these are involved in the TimeZoneStuff

Answer (score 0):

TimeZoneInfo is implemented in Mono, do you need Windows 2000 compatibility? Are you sure you need to stick with .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Use this one for .NET 2.0:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/timezones.aspx